# Use of 'dress' as verb

Tags: usage, verbs, adjectives

My nephew was given to transform a sentence using verb form of 'dress'. The sentence was:

> Her dress was poor.

I suggested him the following sentence.

> She was dressed poorly.

But it occurred to me that here "dressed" is a participle. I desisted from from using a sentence like this:

> She dressed poorly.

Because 'dress' seems to me more like a causative verb. Please suggest the best possible answer.

Comment: 'I suggested him the following sentence.' should be  'I suggested the following sentence to him.'  // 'Dress' is used both intransitively and transitively. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dress) has **dress** verb. 

1 [NO OBJECT] Put on one’s clothes:
_Graham showered and dressed quickly_ / ... 
1.2 [WITH OBJECT] Put clothes on (someone):
_they dressed her in a white hospital gown_

Comment: The sentence is structured in this way(S+V+IDO+DO). Any thing wrong there? Thanks for the nice anecdotes!

Comment: 'I slept a dog' is structured (S+V+DO). Being able to posit an apparent structure is no guarantee of grammaticality. _Suggest_ is not used ditransitively {see eg [Grammar-Quizzes.com](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/ditransitive.html)}.

Comment: Can you elaborate on S+V+IDO+DO? "dress" cannot be used in that structure.

Comment: Look up 'ditransitive verbs' (aka 'bitransitive verbs') on the internet (eg Wikipedia) and here on ELU [eg [Whats wrong with "I'll open you the door"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door/90532#90532)}..

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth thanks for the proper use of 'suggest'.

Answer (score 2):

The exercise wants the student to transform ***"Her dress was poor"*** using a verb form of *dress*.

Answer: ***She dressed poorly***.

---

Why is *"She dressed poorly"* a better answer than *"She **was dressed** poorly"* (or *poorly dressed*)?

First, all of these sentences are a little odd. We don't normally say *"Her dress is poor"*, but we say *"She is well/badly/neatly dressed"*. In *"She is well/badly/neatly dressed"*, *dressed* is an adjective.

As for the other matter that you pointed out, that "*dress* seems like a causative verb", it's true that ***dress*** usually used in the meaning "to put on clothes" (either on yourself or on someone else). But, the verb *dress* is also used when we wear clothes **in a particular style** or **for a particular occasion**. The definitions 1.1 and 1.3 given by Oxford dictionary should make this point clear:

> **[dress](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dress)**
>   1.1 [with adverbial] Wear clothes in a particular way or of a particular type:
>   *'she’s nice-looking and dresses well'*
>
> 1.3 Put on clothes appropriate for a formal occasion:
>   *'we **dressed for dinner** every night'*

So, the best answer is: ***She dressed poorly***.